Centered positions for icons in a radial menu Unity
I am making a radial menu using Images and changing the fill amount, and then rotating it. This is currently working perfectly; instantiating the correct amount of slots with the right sizing and spacing:
private void GenerateSlots()
{
        ClearSlots();

        // Angle per slot, accounting for spacing
        float angleStep = 360f / slotCount;
        float angleOffset = slotSpacing / 2f;

        for (int i = 0; i < slotCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject slotObject = Instantiate(slotPrefab, transform);
            UI_RadialSlot slot = slotObject.GetComponent<UI_RadialSlot>();

            // Calculate the fill amount based on the total slot count
            float fillAmount = (360f - slotSpacing * slotCount) / 360f / slotCount;
            slot.SetFillAmount(fillAmount);

            // Calculate the angle for the current slot (adjusted for spacing)
            float slotStartAngle = (angleStep * i) + angleOffset;
            float slotEndAngle = (angleStep * (i + 1)) - angleOffset;

            slotObject.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, slotStartAngle);

            // Calculate the midpoint angle of the slot for icon placement
            float centerSlotAngle = (slotStartAngle + slotEndAngle) / 2f;

            // Calculate the radians for the midpoint of the slot
            float radians = centerSlotAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

            Vector2 iconPosition = new Vector2(
                Mathf.Cos(radians) * radius,
                Mathf.Sin(radians) * radius
            );

            // Set the icon position at the calculated center of the slot
            slot.SetIconPosition(iconPosition);

            _slots.Add(slot);
        }
        
        // Select the first slot by default
        selectedEntry = _slots[0];
}

Each Slot / Image is a prefab with its own script to help control it:
using System;

public class UI_RadialSlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Image _selectedImage;
    [SerializeField] private Image _unselectedImage;
    [SerializeField] private Image _iconImage;
    private void Awake()
    {
        _unselectedImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        _selectedImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    
    public void SetFillAmount(float fillAmount)
    {
        _unselectedImage.fillAmount = fillAmount;
        _selectedImage.fillAmount = fillAmount;
    }

    public void SelectSlot()
    {
        _unselectedImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        _selectedImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    
    public void DeselectSlot()
    {
        _unselectedImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        _selectedImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    
    public void SetIcon(Sprite icon)
    {
        _iconImage.sprite = icon;
    }
    
    public void SetIconPosition(Vector3 position)
    {
        _iconImage.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        
        // Ensure the icon's anchors are set to the center to prevent stretching issues
        _iconImage.rectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        _iconImage.rectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        
        _iconImage.rectTransform.localPosition = position;
    }
    
    public RectTransform GetIconRectTransform()
    {
        return _iconImage.rectTransform;
    }
}

However, there seems to be a problem with my icon positioning, as it is not centered within the generated slot. What is the problem with my calculations for the centreslotangle? The icon is shown as the blurry circle within the images:



Seems SetIconPosition defines coordinates of the left top corner of icon, so to place center of icon into desired point, you have to shift position by half of icon size like this (iconWidth is pseudocode, use correct corresponding parameter):
      Vector2 iconPosition = new Vector2(
            Mathf.Cos(radians) * radius - iconWidth / 2,
            Mathf.Sin(radians) * radius - iconHeight / 2
        );


@IsaacManzi Did I understand your question properly?
